# Undestanding Recursion with return values in Merge Sort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I'm trying to solve a basic problem in Hackerearth Given an array `A` of size `N`, you need to find the number of ordered pairs `(i,j)`  such that `i < j` and `A[i] > A[j]`.

I was able to find out an idea actually implemented it by having a global variable. But having a global value is not a good practice, hence I tried to pass it as parameter and I couldn't able to solve it. Am stuck with keeping an already returned value and adding an updated value to it.

```
// let ans = 0;

let mergeSort = (left, right, arr, ans) => {
    let i = 0,
        j = 0,
        k = 0;
    let leftLen = left.length,
        rightLen = right.length;
    while (i < leftLen && j < rightLen) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
        arr[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        } else {
        arr[k] = right[j];
        ans += leftLen - i;
        j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < leftLen) {
        arr[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < rightLen) {
        arr[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    return { arr, ans };
};

let divideArray = (arr, ans) => {
    if (arr.length < 2) return { arr, ans };
    let N = arr.length;
    let mid = Math.round(N / 2);
    let left = arr.slice(0, mid);
    let right = arr.slice(mid, N);
    ans = ans;
    divideArray(left, ans);
    divideArray(right, ans);
    let blabla = mergeSort(left, right, arr, ans);
    return blabla;
};

let merge = (arr, ans) => {
    let res = divideArray(arr, ans);
    return res;
};

function main(input) {
    let arr = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5];
    let ans = 0;
    let output = merge(arr, ans);
    console.log('Final', output);
}

main();
```

In mergeSort function When the input of the left array is `[1,4]` and the right array is `[3]` the ans will be updated as `1`, also when the left array is `[1,3,4]` and right is `[2,5]` the ans will be updated as `2`. I would like to add both this ans values and return it as `3`. But somewhere am making a mistake while returning. Any help will be appreciated.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myLtqcd7/1/)

EDIT:

Please note that am trying to achieve it via MergeSort and recursion i know in lot of other ways i can solve this problem for instance i have clearly mentioned i had solved it by having a global variable,which is not a good practice so please provide me a solution only via recursion and merge sort

Comment: You should consider encapsulating all of this functionality in a class

Comment: @Fallenreaper: in these days of easy modules, *why*?

Comment: I guess youre right, with a module, you would encapsulate it.  I just read it as a definition of functions with main function which refrenced them.

Comment: Rather than creating slices of the array, why not pass the original array as a parameter and indexes for the portion of the original array being sorted, and the answer. Then the merge sort only needs to return the answer. A [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) would eliminate the need for recursion, and would not need answer passed in as a parameter (it would just return the answer).

Comment: @rcgldr Dude i wanted to do this via recursion and merge sort so that i can learn recursion in depth

Comment: @KannanT - recursion is ok, but there's no need to create / copy slices of the original array, as the original array can be sorted directly. Using a one time allocated work array would also speed things up a bit.

Comment: @rcgldr ok got it. But any idea on my question how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codepen.io/Santhoshsanz/pen/dybedgm?editors=1112

```
    // let ans = 0;

let mergeSort = (left, right, arr, ans) => {
  // console.log(left)
  // console.log("*****")
  // console.log(right)
  // console.log("*****£££")
    let i = 0,
        j = 0,
        k = 0;
    let leftLen = left.length,
        rightLen = right.length;
    while (i < leftLen && j < rightLen) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
        arr[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        } else {
        arr[k] = right[j];
        ans += leftLen - i;
        j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < leftLen) {
        arr[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < rightLen) {
        arr[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    return { arr, ans };
};

let divideArray = (arr, ans) => {
    if (arr.length < 2) return { arr, ans };
    let N = arr.length;
    let mid = Math.round(N / 2);
    let left = arr.slice(0, mid);
    let right = arr.slice(mid, N);
    ans = ans;
    let lans=divideArray(left, ans).ans;
    let bAns=divideArray(right, ans).ans;
  // console.log(bAns)
    let blabla= mergeSort(left, right, arr, lans+bAns);
  return blabla
};

let merge = (arr, ans) => {
    let res=0+ divideArray(arr, ans).ans;
  // console.log("asdad")
  // console.log(res)
    return res;
};

function main(input) {
    let arr = [1,4,3,2,5];
    let ans = 0;
    let output = merge(arr, ans);
    console.log('Final', output);
}

main();
```

I have persisted the count val inside your divide array and used it to merge the 2 counts from the split array i.e left and right direction split

Comment: This answer may well solve OP's problem, but it would be even better if it explained more **why** it solves OP's problem. Note that the question title asks for *understanding*, not just solving :)

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver can you able to explain how it's working?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to pass an inversion count to divideArray(), it only needs to return a sub_count = left_count + right_count + merged_count. The sub_counts originate from each instance of merging and will be accumulated as recursion returns sub-counts back up the call chain to produce a total_count.

Example of an optimized top down merge sort updated to return an inversion count. A helper function (mergesort()) does a one time allocation of an auxiliary array (aux). To avoid unneeded copying of data, two mutually recursive functions are used, sortarrtoarr() sorts data from arr[] back to arr[], while sortarrtoaux() sorts data from arr[] to aux[]. Each of the mutually recursive functions calls the other in order to change the direction of merge based on the level of recursion.

```js
function merge(arr, aux, bgn, mid, end) {
  var i = bgn;
  var j = mid;
  var k = bgn;
  var cnt = 0;                      // count of inversions
  while(true){
    if(arr[i] <= arr[j]){           // if left element <= right element
      aux[k++] = arr[i++];          //   copy left element
      if(i < mid)                   //   if not end of left run
        continue;                   //     continue back to while
      do                            //   else copy rest of right run
        aux[k++] = arr[j++];        //     and break
      while(j < end);
      break;
    } else {                        // else left element > right element
      cnt += mid - i;               //   arr.slice(i,mid) is > arr[j]
      aux[k++] = arr[j++];          //   copy right element
      if(j < end)                   //   if not end of right run
        continue;                   //     continue back to while
      do                            //   else copy rest of left run
        aux[k++] = arr[i++];        //     and break
      while(i < mid);
      break;
    }
  }
  return cnt;                       // return inversion count
}

// sort from arr[] to aux[]
function sortarrtoaux(arr, aux, bgn, end) {
  if ((end-bgn) < 2){               // if only 1 element
      aux[bgn] = arr[bgn];          //   copy it to aux
      return 0;                     //   return inversion count == 0
  }
  var cnt = 0;                      // inversion count = 0
  var mid = Math.floor(bgn + (end - bgn) / 2);
  cnt += sortarrtoarr(arr, aux, bgn, mid); // sort left  arr back to arr
  cnt += sortarrtoarr(arr, aux, mid, end); // sort right arr back to arr
  cnt += merge(arr, aux, bgn, mid, end);   // merge arr to aux
  return cnt;                       // return inversion count
}

// sort from arr[] back to arr[]
function sortarrtoarr(arr, aux, bgn, end) {
  if ((end-bgn) < 2)                // if only 1 element
    return 0;                       //   return inversion count == 0
  var cnt = 0;                      // inversion count = 0
  var mid = Math.floor(bgn + (end - bgn) / 2);
  cnt += sortarrtoaux(arr, aux, bgn, mid); // sort left  arr to aux
  cnt += sortarrtoaux(arr, aux, mid, end); // sort right arr to aux
  cnt += merge(aux, arr, bgn, mid, end);   // merge aux to arr
  return cnt;                       // return inversion count
}

// entry function for mergesort
function mergesort(arr) {
  if(arr.length < 2)                // if less than 2 elements
      return 0;                     //   return inversion count == 0
  var aux = new Array(arr.length);  // allocate aux[] and start merge sort
  return sortarrtoarr(arr, aux, 0, arr.length);
}

var arr = [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9];
var cnt = mergesort(arr);
console.log(cnt);     
for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i-1] > arr[i]){
    console.log('error');     
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but as am new to the algorithms am having little bit hard time to understand the top down merge sort can you do it in normal merge sort?

Comment: santhosh has answered in the same merge sort way

Comment: @KannanT - I commented the code which should help. As mentioned in my answer, this is an optimized top down merge sort that I already had code for, that I added the inversion count code to. I'm not sure what you mean by "normal" merge sort. This is a normal top down merge sort, but optimized to eliminate having to copy data before or after a merge. With a one time initial copy from arr[] to aux[], a single mergesort function can be used that swaps parameters as shown in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) .

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a hard time figuring why you are writing this with code that's all about a mergesort.  It seems to me that all you need to do is to generate the index pairs where `j` > `i` (a fairly easy task) and then count those for which `A[i] > A[j]`.  Recursion is a fine way (though by no means the only easy way) to create those index pairs.  The rest is a `filter`/`length` combination or a `reduce`.

Here's one variation:

```js
const countDescendingPairs = (xs) => 
  xs .map ((x, i) => xs .slice (i + 1) .filter(y => x > y) .length)
     .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

console .log (
  countDescendingPairs ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9])
)
```

But there are many simple alternatives.

And if you wanted to retrieve those pairs, it's a straightforward modification:

```js
const descendingPairs = (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap (
    (x, i) => 
      xs .slice (i + 1) 
         .filter (y => x > y) 
         .map ((y) => ({x, y}))
  )

console .log (
  descendingPairs ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]) 
)
```

**Updated** to add `flatMap` and to remove the incorrect indices from the second version.  (You can't filter, then expect the old index to still work!)

Comment: Perfect use-case for `Array.prototype.flatMap` - you will avoid those `..., [], [], ...` in the output.

Comment: Doesn't this have quadratic time complexity? I think the merge sort was used by OP because merge sort is O(n lg n).

Comment: @0x499602D2 exactly i wanted to achieve it in merge sort

Comment: @Scott Thanks for your answer mate but please read my edit part of the question

Comment: @user633183: yes of course.  I shouldn't have added that section only as an afterthought.  It's too easy to miss simple things doing that.  Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Scott's answer offers a functional approach. Generators, `function*` below, offer another capable and flexible way of encoding this kind of problem -

```
const descendingPairs = function* (a = [])
{ for (const i of range(0, a.length)) // for all (0 <= i < a.length)
    for (const j of range(0, a.length)) // for all (0 <= i < a.length)
      if (i < j) // such that i < j
        if (a[i] > a[j]) // and a[i] > a[j]
          yield [ a[i], a[j] ] // output descending pair
}
```

We can optimise this by using `i` as the input for the `j` range's `start` -

```
const descendingPairs = function* (a = [])
{ for (const i of range(0, a.length)) // for all (0 < i < a.length)
    for (const j of range(i + 1, a.length)) // for all (i < j < a.length)
      if (a[i] > a[j]) // such that a[i] > a[j]
        yield [ a[i], a[j] ] // output descending pair
}
```

`range` is nicely-encoded using a generator as well -

```
const range = function* (start = 0, stop = 0)
{ for (let x = start; x < stop; x++)
    yield x
}
```

We can output the results of each descending pair -

```
const input =
  [ 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 ]

for (const pair of descendingPairs(input)) 
  console.log(pair)

// [ 4, 3 ]
// [ 4, 2 ]
// [ 3, 2 ]
```

Or we can collect all pairs into an array -

```
Array.from(descendingPairs(input))
// => [ [ 4, 3 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]
```

Or we can simply count them -

```
Array.from(descendingPairs(input)).length
// => 3
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const range = function* (start = 0, stop = 0)
{ for (let x = start; x < stop; x++)
    yield x
}

const descendingPairs = function* (a = [])
{ for (const i of range(0, a.length))
    for (const j of range(i, a.length))
      if (a[i] > a[j])
        yield [ a[i], a[j] ]
}

const input =
  [ 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 ]

console.log(Array.from(descendingPairs(input)))
// [ [ 4, 3 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]

console.log(Array.from(descendingPairs(input)).length)
// 3
```

Comment: Thank you for this answe, but please read my edit part of the question